# How can the google maps Javascript API accept two column (latitude longitude) locations for fusion tables?

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, google-api, maps

In the fusion table you are able to have a two column latitude and longitude address but on the Google Map Javascript API for fusion tables it shows that you must have a single column geocodable address...

Comment: What is fusion table? Can you display your code and give us an example please? See the [help documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is fusion tables https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer. Basically just google made an easy way to take data tied to locations and show it on a google map in different ways. There is some integration with the Google Maps javascript API but it seems as though the API only allows you to use single column locations (addresses which it then geocodes to get a latitude/longitude location) and does not accept two column locations (which is how the fusion tables side accepts latitude and longitude locations).

Comment: This is solved. I had latitude and longitude written like,             
         65.49464147,     32.9427475   (with a space in between)..  Took out the space and it works

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. I had latitude and longitude written with a space in between like:

65.49464147,  32.9427475

Took out the space and it works